# Obfuscating source code using proguard

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I want to obfuscate my source code using java obfuscators. I used proguard as it was the most suggested one. I configured my build.xml as follow

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <property name="proguard.jar.path" value="D:/pro/proguard.jar" />
    <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties"
             classpath="${proguard.jar.path}" />
    <echo message="Obfuscating ${dist.jar}..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/obfuscated"/>
    <proguard printmapping="${build.dir}/obfuscated/${application.title}.map"
              renamesourcefileattribute="SourceFile" ignorewarnings="true">

        <injar  file="${dist.jar}" />
        <outjar file="${build.dir}/obfuscated/${application.title}.jar" />

        <libraryjar path="${javac.classpath}" />          
        <libraryjar file="${java.home}/lib/rt.jar" />
        <libraryjar file="${java.home}/lib/jce.jar" />

        <keepattribute name="InnerClasses" />
        <keepattribute name="SourceFile" />
        <keepattribute name="LineNumberTable" />
        <keepattribute name="Deprecated" />
        <keepattribute name="*Annotation*" />
        <keepattribute name="Signature" />
        <keepattribute name="Exceptions" />

        <keep access="public">
            <field  access="public protected" />
            <method access="public protected" />
        </keep>

        <keepclassmembernames access="public">
            <method type      ="java.lang.Class"
                    name      ="class$"
                    parameters="java.lang.String" />
            <method type      ="java.lang.Class"
                    name      ="class$"
                    parameters="java.lang.String,boolean" />
        </keepclassmembernames>

        <keepclasseswithmembernames>
            <method access="native" />
        </keepclasseswithmembernames>

        <keepclassmembers extends="java.lang.Enum">
            <method access="public static"
                    type="**[]"
                    name="values"
                    parameters="" />
            <method access="public static"
                    type="**"
                    name="valueOf"
                    parameters="java.lang.String" />
        </keepclassmembers>

        <keepnames implements="java.io.Serializable"/>
        <keepclassmembers implements="java.io.Serializable">
            <field  access    ="final"
                    type      ="long"
                    name      ="serialVersionUID" />
            <field  access    ="!static !transient"
                    name      ="**"/>
            <field  access    ="!private"
                    name      ="**"/>
            <method access    ="!private"
                    name      ="**"/>
            <method access    ="private"
                    type      ="void"
                    name      ="writeObject"
                    parameters="java.io.ObjectOutputStream" />
            <method access    ="private"
                    type      ="void"
                    name      ="readObject"
                    parameters="java.io.ObjectOutputStream" />
            <method type      ="java.lang.Object"
                    name      ="writeReplace"
                    parameters="" />
            <method type      ="java.lang.Object"
                    name      ="readResolve"
                    parameters="" />
        </keepclassmembers>

    </proguard>
    <copy file="${build.dir}/obfuscated/${application.title}.jar" tofile="${dist.jar}" overwrite="true"/>
    <delete dir="${build.dir}/obfuscated"/>
</target>
```

But it results in following error :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method must be overridden in [proguard.optimize.peephole.ClassMerger] if ever called
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitAnyClass(SimplifiedVisitor.java:47)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitLibraryClass(SimplifiedVisitor.java:59)
    at proguard.classfile.LibraryClass.accept(LibraryClass.java:301)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.subclassesAccept(ProgramClass.java:433)
    at proguard.optimize.peephole.VerticalClassMerger.visitProgramClass(VerticalClassMerger.java:83)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:346)
    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:125)
    at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:565)
    at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:307)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:116)
    at proguard.ant.ProGuardTask.execute(ProGuardTask.java:316)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's a choice, why not?

Comment: See if this link can help you: http://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/384/

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: It is must in my situation to protect it atleast from decompiling.

Comment: 1) Obfuscation does not protect code from a determined hacker. 2) Someone who can't work the ProGuard software has around 1 in a million chance of making anything **worth** stealing.  My advice a)  put extra effort into application updates. That way, the hackers are trying to 'hit a moving target'. b) Sell support, not software.

Comment: @Igor Rodriguez: thnx :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes, changing gender is a choice, and so some people do it and I won't blame them, because it's THEIR choice. Also, you don't know if the program is worth or not. In the same way, selling support is not the best way of getting profit for all companies, and it's also their choice. I think that when people ask a question here they are not looking for help in business management, but with technical problems.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: My head is very well, deep in the sand, where we see not only one big picture but many of them. Thanks for your consideration. :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the option -ignorewarnings, you should try solving the warnings that you get. You don't mention warnings in your question, but chances are that you have specified library classes (with -libraryjars) that depend on program classes (with -injars), which is not allowed. Cfr. ProGuard manual > Introduction.